# Get rows with difference of dates being one

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle10g, date-arithmetic

I have the following table and rows defined in [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/76226/2)

I need to select rows from products table where difference between two rows `start_date` and 
`nvl(return_date,end_date)` is 1. i.e. `start_date` of current row and `nvl(return_date,end_date)` of previous row should be one

For example

`PRODUCT_NO TSH098` and `PRODUCT_REG_NO FLDG`, the `END_DATE` is **August, 15 2012** and 
`PRODUCT_NO TSH128` and `PRODUCT_REG_NO FLDG` `start_date` is **August, 16 2012**, so the difference is only of a day.

How can I get the desired output using sql.

Any help is highly appreciable.

Thanks

Comment: In your comments you have added extra requirements, regarding join and filtering conditions.  You have wasted people's time by not including all the requirements in your initial question.  Please make amends by rounding up all those editions and editing your question so it reflects your actual requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`lag`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96540/functions56a.htm#83619) analytical function to get access to a row at a given physical offset prior to the current position. According to your sorting order it might look like this(not so elegant though).

```
select *
  from products p
  join (select *
         from(select p.Product_no
                   , p.Product_Reg_No
                   , case 
                       when (lag(start_date, 1, start_date) over(order by product_reg_no)-
                            nvl(return_date, end_date)) = 1 
                            then lag(start_date, 1, start_date) 
                                   over(order by product_reg_no) 
                        end start_date
                   , End_Date
                   , Return_Date
               from products p 
              order by 2,1 desc
              )
        where start_date is not null
       ) s
    on (p.start_date = s.start_date or p.end_date = s.end_date)
 order by 2, 1 desc
```

[**SQL FIddle DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/76226/171)

Comment: Thanks for the solution. For `PRODUCT_REG_NO='FLDG'` there are `PRODUCT_NO TSH098` and `TSH12` having `start_date` and `nvl(return_date, end_date)` difference of one, but that is not selected. I would like to select all those records with dates difference of one.

Comment: Nicholas Thanks a lot as this looks good and I am currently testing my results. I have one small doubt i.e. where to include my where condition like `where PRODUCT_REG_NO='FLDG'`? It should be after where `start_date is not null` or just above the `last order by 2, 1 desc` Regards

Comment: it may be just above last order if you want to filter final result

Comment: As I am testing the results, please check the following, I did not execute any results  [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4915c/2) where as `select *
  from products p` has records Thanks

Comment: This is all about sorting order. In your question you've been sorting by product_no, and product_reg_no. In the last example you gave me you are ordering by start_date (3) ( here is an example http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4915c/28). You just have to decide what columns you want to use for sorting data

Comment: I need to sort by start_date,product_no, and product_reg_no. I will test your latest solution. Thanks

Comment: Another test I did with your latest solution and did not fetch any results [sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/76226/189) Thanks

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16741/discussion-between-polppan-and-nicholas-krasnov)

Answer (score 2):

In SQL, `date + X` adds X days to the date.  So you can:

```
select  * 
from    products
where   start_date + 1 = nvl(end_date, return_date)
```

If the dates could contain a time part, use `trunc` to remove the time part:

```
select  * 
from    products
where   trunc(start_date) + 1 = trunc(nvl(end_date, return_date))
```

[Live example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5f4b9/1/0)

Comment: What I am looking for is those rows where difference of `start_date` and `nvl(return_date,end_date)` is 1. i.e.  `start_date` of current row and `nvl(return_date,end_date)` of previous row should be one e.g. **PRODUCT_REG_NO FLDG** with **PRODUCT_NO TSH098** `start_date` and **PRODUCT_NO TSH128** `nvl(return_date,end_date)` is one. I hope I explained properly.

Comment: Aha, I missed the "previous row" part.  Gotta go now, but have a look at the [lag function](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/lag-lead-analytic-functions.php)

Answer (score 2):

The way to compare the current row with the previous row is to user the LAG() function.  Something like this:

```
select * from 
(
select p.* 
       , lag (end_date) over 
         (order by start_date )
         as prev_end_date
       , lag (return_date) over 
         (order by start_date )
         as prev_return_date
from products p
)
where (trunc(start_date) - 1) = trunc(nvl(prev_return_date, prev_end_date))
order by 2,1 desc
```

However, this will not return the results you desire, because you have not defined a mechanism for defining a sort order.  And without a sort order the concept of "previous row" is meaningless.

However, what you can do is this:

```
select p1.* 
       , p2.*
from products p1 cross join products p2
where (trunc(p2.start_date) - 1) = trunc(nvl(p1.return_date, p1.end_date))
order by 2, 1 desc
```

This SQL queries your table twice, filtering on the basis of dates.  The each row in the result set contains a record from each table.  If a given start_date matches more than one end_date or vice versa you will get records for multiple hits.

Comment: Not sure why are you performing a `CROSS JOIN`? Outer rows have no clue there imo. Wouldn't be enough to do `INNER JOIN` like: `FROM p1 JOIN p2 ON (trunc(p2.start_date) - 1) = trunc(nvl(p1.return_date, p1.end_date))`?

Comment: @WojtusJ - both solutions return the same result.  I prefer the CROSS JOIN because it conveys the intent better; to my mind INNER JOIN implies a key-ed relationship.  But your taste or interpretation may vary.

Comment: I see, it actually makes sense. :-)

Comment: @WojtusJ - perhaps the WITH clauses confused the issue: they were relics of an earlier attempt to solve it, and I should have refactored them out completely (which I have now done).

Answer (score 2):

I am under the impression you only want the matching dates differing by 1 day if the product reg no matches. So I simply joint it and I think this is what you want

```
select p1.product_reg_no,
       p1.product_no product_no_1,
       p2.product_no product_no_2,
       p1.start_date start_date_1,
       nvl(p2.return_date,p2.end_date) return_or_end_date_2
  from products p1
  join products p2 on (p1.product_reg_no = p2.product_reg_no)
where  p1.start_date-1 = nvl(p2.return_date,p2.end_date)
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/76226/154)

If I was wrong with the grouping then just leave the join condition away which with the given example products table brings the same result

```
select p1.product_reg_no,
       p1.product_no product_no_1,
       p2.product_no product_no_2,
       p1.start_date start_date_1,
       nvl(p2.return_date,p2.end_date) return_or_end_date_2
  from products p1, products p2
where  p1.start_date-1 = nvl(p2.return_date,p2.end_date)
```

[SQL Fiddle 2](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/76226/157)

Now you say the difference is 1 day. I automatically assumed that start_date is 1 day higher than the nvl(return_date,end_date). Also I assumed that the date is always midnight. But to have all that also excluded you can work with trunc and go in both directions:

```
select p1.product_reg_no,
       p1.product_no product_no_1,
       p2.product_no product_no_2,
       p1.start_date start_date_1,
       nvl(p2.return_date,p2.end_date) return_or_end_date_2
  from products p1, products p2
where  trunc(p1.start_date)-1 = trunc(nvl(p2.return_date,p2.end_date))
    or trunc(p1.start_date)+1 = trunc(nvl(p2.return_date,p2.end_date))
```

[SQL Fiddle 3](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/76226/163)

And this all works because dates (not timestamp) can be calculated by adding and subtracting.

EDIT: Following your comment you want return_date `or` end_date to be compared and equal dates are also wanted:

```
select p1.product_reg_no,
       p1.product_no product_no_1,
       p2.product_no product_no_2,
       p1.start_date start_date_1,
       p2.return_date return_date_2,
       p2.end_date end_date_2
  from products p1, products p2
where  trunc(p1.start_date)   = trunc(p2.return_date)
    or trunc(p1.start_date)-1 = trunc(p2.return_date)
    or trunc(p1.start_date)+1 = trunc(p2.return_date)
    or trunc(p1.start_date)   = trunc(p2.end_date)
    or trunc(p1.start_date)-1 = trunc(p2.end_date)
    or trunc(p1.start_date)+1 = trunc(p2.end_date)
```

[SQL Fiddle 4](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/76226/175)

Comment: Thanks for the help. One main problem I am facing is this. For `PRODUCT_REG_NO='FLDG'` there are `PRODUCT_NO TSH098` and `TSH12` having `start_date` and `nvl(return_date, end_date)` difference of one, but that is not selected. I would like to select all those records with dates difference of one. How can I do this? Regards

Comment: `TSH098` has `return_date` 31-May-2012. `TSH012` has start_date 18-Jun-2012. So the condition does not match. `NVL` does say take the first value but if it is null take the second value. But I think I am guessing what you want let me add one more.

Comment: @Polppan Please see my edit. By the way. Do you need the matches only within a PRODUCT_REG_NO or over the whole table?

Comment: Hol Match should be within PRODUCT_REG_NO.

Comment: @Polppan _"TSH098 and TSH12 having start_date and nvl(return_date, end_date) difference of one"_ They don't have difference of 1. TSH098 `start_date` and TSH012 (there is no TSH12) `end_date` have difference of 0. Could you elaborate why you think they should be selected?

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo error. It is THS128 and TSH098, they are having difference of 1. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You mean like this?

```
SELECT T2.*
FROM PRODUCTS T1
    JOIN PRODUCTS T2 ON (
        nvl(T1.end_date, T1.return_date) + 1 = T2.start_date
    );
```

In [your SQL Fiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a9bdd/7), it returns:

```
PRODUCT_NO    PRODUCT_REG_NO    START_DATE                          END_DATE                            RETURN_DATE
TSH128        FLDG              August, 16 2012 00:00:00-0400       September, 15 2012 00:00:00-0400    (null)
TSH125        SCRW              August, 08 2012 00:00:00-0400       September, 07 2012 00:00:00-0400    (null)
TSH137        SCRW              September, 08 2012 00:00:00-0400    October, 07 2012 00:00:00-0400      (null)
```

- TSH128 is returned for the reasons you already explained.
- TSH125 is returned because TSH116 `end_date` is August, 07 2012.
- TSH137 is returned because TSH125 `end_date` is September, 07 2012.

If you want to compare only rows within the same `product_reg_no`, it's easy to add that to the JOIN condition. If you want both "directions" of the 1-day difference, it's easy to add that too.

Comment: I need to have only those rows with start date of current row and previous row difference being one matching PRODUCT_REG_NO. Thanks

Comment: @Polppan Fine, just add that to the JOIN condition, as I already mentioned. BTW, the word "previous" has a meaning only in the context of an ordering. What is your ordering?